# jQuery Image Gallery with jCarousel with changing preview

Tags: jquery

I found this script: http://www.queness.com/post/3036/create-a-custom-jquery-image-gallery-with-jcarousel

which has everything I need except one thing. On right side selection is changing but preview on left side is same all the time.

Does anyone knows how to change this?

Comment: Hey, so the functionality is when you click on the right side carousel then the left will change, seems like correct behavior?

Comment: Demo works for me, what is not working for you ? or whathaveyoutried?

Comment: it changes on `click`, you want it to be changing as the selection on the right changes?

Comment: I need an option when scroll on right side changes that select thumb and on the right is active that preview on the left also change.

Comment: @Tarun - I need automaticaly.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://joynag.net/demos/jcarousal/

Comment: @Joy - yes but I doesn't have arows :(

Comment: Check now. Forgot to upload arrows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `itemFirstInCallback` callback of `jCarousal` to change the preview like this

```
function mycarousel_itemFirstInCallbackBeforeAnimation(carousel, item, idx, state) {

    $('div#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({'opacity': '0.5'});
    $('div#slideshow-carousel li a').each(function () {

       if ($('a',item).has('span').length) 
          $('a',item).children('img').css({'opacity': '1.0'});

    });
    if (!$('a',item).has('span').length) {
       $('div#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({'opacity': '0.5'});
       $('a',item).stop(true, true).children('img').css({'opacity': '1.0'});
    }

    $('div#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active');        
    $('div#slideshow-main li.' + $(item).find('a').attr('rel')).addClass('active');
        }
```

Then you can call jCarousal with the above callback

```
$('#carousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: true,
    scroll: 1,
    auto: 2,
    wrap: 'last',
    itemFirstInCallback: {
     onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemFirstInCallbackBeforeAnimation
    },
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
});
```

[DEMO](http://joynag.net/demos/jcarousal/)

[ZIP Bundle](http://joynag.net/demos/jcarousal/jcarousal.zip)

Comment: It has one bug. Thumb is checked first and then jumps to fourth, and preview is on start third and then jumps to fourth. Could you pls check this error?

Comment: Not is that ok but slide is going 5. image and then goes from first again. Can you pls solve this error :)

Comment: Sorry, what you want is tough to achieve in current setup. As you can see right panel have 3 items visible and left panel have only 1. So without hacking the core of jCarousal, I think it tough to do what you want or maybe I dont know how to do that.